# How to count the rows based on a filter in excel?

Tags: excel-formula

I have an excel sheet with 2 columns in it: `StoreState` and `RequestResult`.
And records are somewhat like:

```
StoreState  RequestResult
FL          Success
FL          Success
FL          Success
OH          Success
FL          Success
OH          ParsingError
FL          Success
ND          Success
CA          Success
FL          ParsingError
```

How can I count the records per state with successful and failed requests?

I would like to filter my records by `StoreState`

Comment: Use a Pivot table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `=SUBTOTAL(3,A2:A11)`  Answers need to be 30 char long